# Calling Feedburner Ping URL In PHP

Tags: php, feedburner

I"ve been wondering how I can ask feedburner to update my rss feed by pinging them through php.  Is there a way to call the URL for pinging in php?

example of ping url:

```
http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/pingSubmit?bloglink=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file_get_contents("http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/pingSubmit?bloglink=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com");
```

That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Pinging Feedburner is now deprecated.
(IMHO Google has done a pretty good job of forcing users off of Feedburner without actually discontinuing it [which is certainly their ulterior motive].)